# Getting the value of div element nested inside another div i.e, `chart` to make it undefined while closing

Tags: angular, angular7

I'm looking for a solution where I can make the value of 
          `this.stock1 = undefined` on closing the box.

```
     <div style="width: 30%;" #closeable1>
        <input class="rd" type="radio" name="sub-chart" checked/> 
        <small>Low</small>
        <input class="rd" type="radio" name="sub-chart"/><small>Medium</small>
        <input class="rd" type="radio" name="sub-chart"/><small>High</small>
        <input class="rd" type="radio" name="sub-chart"/><small>NA</ small>
        <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" 
         (click)="closing1(closeable1)">
            <span aria-hidden="true">x</span>
        </button>
          <hr>
        <div style="width:98%;" [chart]="stock1"></div>
      </div>


      In the above code, when I close the box, I want the value of `stock1`,  
      Which is there in .ts file to be set to undefined while closing the box.
      Something like,
```

// Hello.ts

```
    `this.stock`;
      closing1 (closeable: HTMLDivElement, stock?: any) {
       // is there way to make the value of
        this.stock1 = undefined; // before closing
        closeable.remove();
      }
```

How to make the value of this.stock1 = undefined while closing?

You can refer the image attached for reference.
 [image: iMage Link]

Comment: How/Where have you defined `stock1`?

Comment: this.stock = stock1; this statement is there in .ts file and its getting the value to generate the chart. and that is getting plotted in the box. Once the box is closed, I want to make the this.stock1  = undefined, bcz I can re use for different data.
In nutshell, this.stock1 is having data for plotting the graph coming from .ts file.